# Copy data from Eclipse RAP GridTableViewer

Tags: copy, eclipse-rap

I am using [GridTableViewer](https://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/doc/3.9/guide/reference/api/org/eclipse/nebula/jface/gridviewer/GridTableViewer.html) from Eclipse RAP 3.11.  The user can select rows.  However, when the user clicks on the browser's Edit > Copy menu, nothing is copied to the user's clipboard.  The user's clipboard's original contents remain intact.  How do I allow for copying to the clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT Clipboard is not supported in RAP. There are lot of discussions about it in RAP forum.

360790: Add Clipboard Support to RAP
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=360790